# In template driven kendo-grid method when edit click need to focus the clicked cell in the row

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, focus, cell, editablegrid

In template driven kendo-grid method when edit click need to focus the clicked cell in the row. Because if it's not available just have to click two times in the cell to edit the content. (Used form controls for data binding.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do with find method with specific row index and column index to set your focus.

Here code for your reference.

```
var ColIndex=2, grid = $("#grdTest").data("kendoGrid");
setTimeout(function () {
grid.tbody.find("tr:eq(" + (grid._data.length - 1) + ") td:eq(" + (ColIndex - 1) + ") input").focus();
}, 400);
```

I hope this will help you.